# SSRS Cache Report Parameters Previous Week

Tags: caching, reporting-services, parameters

Is there a way to set the Parameter Values in the Cache Refresh Plan window to use the previous Sunday?  The field is a Date/Time field and will not let me enter code such as =DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -7,DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, 1-Weekday(today),Today)).   It is looking for date format.  Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you receiving an error when you try to plug that expression in?

Answer (score 0):

I'm unaware of any parameter caching options. However, you should be able to get a default value to work. Perhaps the expression below will work.

```
=DateAdd(dd,1-  DatePart(dw, CDate(Today())), CDate(Today()))
```

If you still can't get it to work, another option would be to add a data set that spits out the value. You could use something like:

```
SELECT DATEADD(dd,1-  DATEPART(dw, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)), CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))
```